# If $x=1+\sqrt2 +\sqrt3$ , then how to evaluate $2x^4-8x^3-5x^2+26x-28$ without using calculator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x=1+\sqrt2 +\sqrt3$ , then how to evaluate $2x^4-8x^3-5x^2+26x-28$ without using calculator?

One way is to calculate $x^2 , x^3 \& x^4$ from $x$ and then substitute in the required expression, but it will be very complicated and also time consuming;
So,is there any better method via which we can evaluate the given expression value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$(x-1)^2=(\sqrt3+\sqrt2)^2$$

$$\iff x^2-2x+1=5+2\sqrt6$$

Squaring both sides   $$(2\sqrt6)^2=(x^2-2x-4)^2$$

$$x^4+4x^2+16-4x^3-8x^2+16x=24 \iff x^4-4x^3-4x^2+16x-8=0$$
Finally

$$2x^4-8x^3-5x^2+26x-28=2(x^4-4x^3-4x^2+16x-8)+3(x^2-2x+1)-15$$